# Is there an app that will notify me (in notifications center) if a process is using up a high percentage of CPU for a specified amount of time?

Tags: macos, notifications, cpu, power-management

The other day, I was sitting in a coffee shop working, when I looked down to find that 25% of my battery was left.

I looked at my Activity Monitor and saw that the time machine process was going at 90% for a while (as long as I was watching it).

Are there any apps that can notify me if a process is at a certain level for a certain amount of time?

Comment: See also: [Notifying when using high CPU. Via AppleScript or Automator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24129903/411282)

Answer (score 6):

You could run a script like this every minute with cron or launchd:

```
#!/bin/bash

cpulimit=50
prefix=${TMPDIR}cron_cpu
current=$(ps -erco %cpu,command | tail -n+2 | sed 's/^ *//')
echo "$current" > $prefix$(date +%s)
a=($prefix*); for ((i=0;i<=${#a[@]}-3;i++)); do rm "${a[i]}"; done
[[ $(awk '{s+=$1}END{printf "%i",s}' <<< "$current") -lt $cpulimit ]] && exit
averages=$(awk '{cpu=$1;sub(/[^ ]+ /,"");a[$0]+=cpu;c[$0]++}END{for(i in a){printf "%.1f %s\n",a[i]/c[$0],i}}' $prefix* | sort -rn)
if [[ $(awk '{s+=$1}END{printf "%i",s}' <<< "$averages") -ge $cpulimit ]]; then
    terminal-notifier -title "CPU use" -message "$(head -n5 <<< "$averages" | paste -sd / -)"
fi
```

If the average CPU use in the last three samples is over 50%, it uses [terminal-notifier](https://github.com/alloy/terminal-notifier) to display the processes that used the most CPU.

You could also use [MenuMeters](http://www.ragingmenace.com/software/menumeters/) to display total CPU use in the menu bar:

[image]

Or run a script like this with [GeekTool](http://projects.tynsoe.org/en/geektool/):

`for i in {1..4}; do ps -erco %cpu,command | tail -n+2; sleep 1; done | sed 's/^ *//' | grep -v GeekTool | awk '{cpu=$1;sub(/[^ ]+ /,"");a[$0]+=cpu;c[$0]++}END{for(i in a){printf "%.1f %s\n",a[i]/c[$0],i}}' | sort -rn`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a variant built off of the answer from @Lri.  It will stay silent if there are no processes above a threshold (set to 60 here) but does not do averaging across samples, so may give more one-off noise.  Like the other answer, you will need to install [terminal-notifier](https://github.com/julienXX/terminal-notifier).

Save the script below to a file (called, e.g., `/Users/goldberg/cpu_notify` and made executable):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Post a notification if a process is over a CPU limit

# see ~/Library/LaunchAgents/goldberg.cpu_notify.plist

notify=/usr/local/bin/terminal-notifier

cpulimit=60
active=$(ps -erco %cpu,command \
    | head -3 \
    | grep -vE -e '\b(CPU COMMAND|bash|sed|awk|ps|grep|head)\b' \
    | awk "\$1 > $cpulimit")

# Skip if empty.
[ -z "${active}" ] || $notify  -title "CPU use" -message "$active"
```

If you'd like a log of when particular processes are overactive (I have to watch out for `ntpd`, for instance) add a line to the script like the following:

```
echo "${active}" | grep -e SymDaemon -e ntpd | sed 's/^/'"$(date) "'/'  >> ~/tmp/symd-notes
```

...and for `launchd`, save the file below with a name like `~/Library/LaunchAgents/goldberg.cpu_notify.plist`.  Use [`launchctl -w`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/217455/19289) to identify the plist to `launchd` (and `launchctl list` to check it's there.)

This is set to 300 seconds (5 minutes) interval, and you will need to edit the line that points to the script.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>goldberg.cpu_notify</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Users/goldberg/bin/cpu_notify</string>
    <key>ServiceDescription</key>
    <string>High CPU process notification</string>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>300</integer>
    <key>ThrottleInterval</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Here's [more about launchd and launchctl](https://superuser.com/q/930389/72975).

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting an alternative to Notification Center: Dock.

Although there's no configuration for the duration the process has been running, it's live.

> [image]

In Activity Monitor app, View menu > Dock Icon > Show CPU usage.

If any of the bars jump up, you can check the process right away.