# What's an effective way to proactively spot runaway processes?

Tags: macos, cpu

Sometimes my Mac ends up with a runaway process; a process that's hogging all the CPU. Often it's Firefox, but I've had a few others recently. Normally I don't spot this for a while until I notice my fan is running like crazy. This can kill battery life. Is there any way to effectively be proactively be notified about these processes?

---

Bonus points if the solution doesn't involve paid-for software. Extra bonus points if I can use an inbuilt facility of OS X.

*Note*: I'm not looking for how to locate and kill runaway processes; I already know how to to do that with `top` once I suspect there may be one. I would like to be pro-actively notified that a process has been chewing more than X% cpu for Ys time.

Comment: On my mac mini the fans audibly start up when a process starts using much CPU

Comment: A similar earlier question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/90270