# How can I take a command line tool and program launchd to run it?

Tags: macos, launchd

I am trying to get Offlineimap to run every 5 minutes with launchd. I do not know why it doesn't work and the log file is not written on the specified location. I am running MacOS Mojave on a 2018 MacBook Pro. Can anyone tell me what the problem is with the following plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
        "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"> 
     <plist version="1.0">
      <dict> 
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>local.check.gmail.plist</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
          <string>/usr/local/bin/offlineimap</string>
      <string>-q</string>
      <string>-u</string>
      <string>quiet</string>
      <string>-a</string>
      <string>gmail</string>
        </array>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/Users/ereraa/log/local.check.gmail.error.log</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Users/ereraa/log/local.check.gmail.log</string>
       <key>RunAtLoad</key>
       <true/>
       <key>StartInterval</key>
       <integer>60</integer>
       <key>KeepAlive</key>
       <dict>
     <key>NetworkState</key>
     <true/>
       </dict>
       <key>TimeOut</key>
       <integer>180</integer>
       <key>ServiceDescription</key>
       <string>Offlineimap Gmail</string>
      </dict>
    </plist>
```

Running Offlineimap in the terminal with the exact same arguments works flawlessly. I should perhaps mention that I tried to set up a cronjob; in that case I got the error message that Python could not be found.

Comment: Have a look at the man page for `launchd.plist`,, especially the `ProgramArguments` and `Program` keys.

Comment: Our canonical "what tools help debug launch daemon plist syntax" suggests tools to make the debugging obvious. They coded all the rules and syntax and pre-flight checks and you get actionable pop ups. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/217453/configure-launchd

Comment: Also - what does [stderr and stdout show if you add those sections to the plist](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/217456/5472)? In fact, what error code are you getting when you try and run the plist as you posted it? You say you get errors, posting the text of that error and how to reproduce it would possibly help us help you.

Comment: I have tried to find the answer here on Stackexchange, but I cannot understand the problem (fairly new to MacOS coming from Debian). And as far as the stderr regards, the plist does not seem to produce any such file...

Comment: Runatload and time interval looks an odd combination

Comment: I am still not sure about what the problem was, but after having removed the Runatload key, it just works. I also added the path to Python. Not sure if that has anything to do with anything. My problem is solved at any rate! Thanks for taking the time to help me out!